# How can I solve problem when I want to use ogr in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, gdal, ogr

I'm writing code with Django code. When I want to call spatial data using gdal, it suddenly encounters the following error. It should be noted that gdal is installed on the system and works properly.

> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _gdal: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems you missed importing something required in your code. If you can share your code the community can help you.

Comment: @enesislam I have a simmelar question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72645113/importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-gdal-the-specified-procedure-was