# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _gdal: The specified procedure was not found

Tags: python, django, pip, ddl, gdal

I am trying to install GDAL and I always get this error message: ImportError:

```
DLL load failed while importing _gdal: The specified procedure was not found.
```

I have the `Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`
and use the wheel: GDAL-3.3.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

Can it be that I am using the wrong wheel version and if so how do I find the right one?
where you can finde the wheels: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)

my code:

```
from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
from traceback import print_tb
from osgeo import gdal 
from numpy import meshgrid
from numpy import linspace

map = Basemap(projection='tmerc', 
              lat_0=0, lon_0=3,
              llcrnrlon=1.819757266426611, 
              llcrnrlat=41.583851612359275, 
              urcrnrlon=1.841589961763497, 
              urcrnrlat=41.598674173123)

ds = gdal.Open("C:/elevation.tif")
data = ds.ReadAsArray()

x = linspace(0, map.urcrnrx, data.shape[1])
y = linspace(0, map.urcrnry, data.shape[0])

xx, yy = meshgrid(x, y)

cs = map.contour(xx, yy, data, range(400, 1500, 100), cmap = plt.cm.cubehelix)
plt.clabel(cs, inline=True, fmt='%1.0f', fontsize=12, colors='k')

plt.show()
```

(this is a basemap example)

Comment: This is likely a DLL conflict for the `geos_c.dll` included with the basemap and gdal packages. Try to install latest basemap from the same site where you downloaded the gdal wheel.

Comment: Hi  @cgohlke   I have now downloaded basemap from the site and noticed that Antarctica is halfway down the map (see the image in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72598996/indexerror-too-many-indices-for-array-array-is-1-dimensional-but-2-were-index/72684102#72684102 ) What can I do?

Comment: My search for gdal dlls can help https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/456857/6295